# ASP.Net 301 redirect error

Tags: asp.net

I am currently trying to create a 301 redirect, but am getting some strange error..

This is the code that i am using: (file is called test.aspx)

```
<html>
<head>
<script runat="server">
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.XXXXX.com/");
}
</script>   
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But i am getting this error:

```
Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.XXXXX.com/");
```

though this isn't a permanent HTTP 301.

In the [.NET Fx 4.0+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectpermanent.aspx) you can:

```
Response.RedirectPermanent("http://www.XXXXX.com/");
```

If you want to go manual or are using an earlier version of the framework, you must `Response.End` in your `Page_Load` event handler. (If you do not you send some headers and then you send a body that isn't applicable to the headers.)

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.XXXXX.com/");
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Do i replace the above with that?

Comment: Replace your two lines with the `Response.Redirect`, yes. You don't have to manually specify headers.

Comment: What if you remove the entire `<script runat="server">...</script>` block entirely? Do you still get errors? You can also set `<customErrors mode="off" />` in the `web.config` to get a detailed error message or debug the problem on your local machine (which is the recommended approach).